# Strange behaviour of doBuildQuery with where case in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Code:

```
 class ProxyListFormFilter extends BaseProxyListFormFilter
 ...
  public function doBuildQuery(array $values) {

     $q = parent::doBuildQuery($values);

     $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();
     $q->addWhere($rootAlias . '.proxy_type = ?', 'regular');

 return $q; 
}
```

I just did this to filter as default 1 column by a fixed type.
The column is defined this way:

```
     proxy_type:
  type: enum(16)
  values:
    - regular
    #- php_gateway
```

The very strange behaviour is that i get an empty list with no rows but the counter at the end shows: 3 results.

What I'm doing wrong or missing ?

Comment: Add 2 prints in your code to check the sql generated: one after the parent doBuildQuery and one after your extra addWhere... Then you can check that SQL and try it out directly to see if the query is faulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fault..Basically due to caching after applying the filter the page still pointed to a huge page number while the returned records where only 3. So no display for a page which do not contain the first 3 records.